# Content url does not display image on firefox browser, is there a work around that doesn't require removing alt tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I want to serve different images to users of my website depending on screen size, however using content url in css does not work with firefox and requires the image to be served also with the :after css attribute (see below):

ALL BROWSERS:

```
.AnImage{ 
  content: url("images/Home/2560/SimonAndGeorgia.jpg");
}
```

FIREFOX:

```
.AnImage:after { 
  content: url("images/Home/2560/SimonAndGeorgia.jpg");
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the alt is displayed in firefox and has to be removed!
I want alt tags and i want to server different images to different sized devices to speed up downloads.

It's 2017 surely someone has a solution so i can do both??? Please

Comment: Can you create a minimal example please? This will give myself and others something to work with. Thank you.

Comment: As your "Firefox" solution works in all browsers you can use it not only in firefox

Comment: HTML: `<div id="mydiv"></div>` CSS: `#mydiv::after {content: url('/img/the-img.png'); }` works in FF, IE (starting from v8 emulation), and Google Chrome. Which browsers don't support it?

Comment: The same is true for `#mydiv:after {content: url('/img/the-img.png'); }`. Works in FF, IE, and GC.

Comment: Actually the right selector is `::after` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: Does OP have a preference for setting content directly on `.AnImage`? I do wonder why he's not using `background-url`.

Comment: `content` CSS property is defined for `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content Some browsers may offer some *extended* implementation.

Comment: Yeah. The W3C agrees https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#content-uri

Comment: I can use a background image, but i want to have alt tags for SEO and i want different images depending on screen size, im wondering if i can render the alt text behind the image or off screen, or should i use javascript to remove them in firefox only. e.g.?                                         
                                                                                                                  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++)
{
  elements[i].removeAttribute('alt');
}

Comment: What about having *all* your size-specific content in the html, but turn `display: none;` on and off with css depending on viewport size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up changing all my content:url css to also include the :after which works with firefox.

```
.AnImage, .AnImage:after{ 
  content: url("images/Home/2560/SimonAndGeorgia.jpg");
}
```

Coupling with this javascript code to remove the alt tags within firefox:

```
 // Firefox 1.0+
    if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {
        //alert("we are using firefox");
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) { 
     elements[i].removeAttribute('alt'); }
    }
```

Thus the alt tags are there for SEO, however are removed when using Firefox.

Comment: This solution does not work for bootstrap carousel's eventually i just removed content:url and added used src. Does anyone know a solution for this? Using display: none doesn't work well because the images are all loaded in most browsers thus not saving bandwidth/speed